# Displaying Icons in Safari

Tags: html

Inserted this in my html header.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font- 
awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Nothing.

The funny thing is that email icon displays fine

```
fa-envelope
```

I wonder if it's just that Safari only supports certain fa-fas? Or if it has its own special list of fa-fas?

As I understand, there is something called favicons? Safari Favorites? Can I use these. What is the code?

Comment: your css link seems to be incorrect.
use this one instead: https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: also, favicon is not for displaying icons inside the page, it's the icon that shows up on the tab before the page title, besides it's not safari favourites.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: It worked. Great job